# RXJS Reattach Listeners after Websocket Disconnect

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I'm using RXJS with Angular, and have a websocket service that is a simple wrapper over a RXJS WebSocketSubject.

I also have some services that need to subscribe to this service for data. On the init of these services, they subscribe to the "base" websocket.

This works fine until the base websocket loses connection to the server. It correctly re-establishes itself, and so I am able to push data to the server. However, the subscriptions that my other services had don't get re-applied, so I can't receive any data.

What would be the recommended way to fix this? Thanks!

Base websocket (simplified):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { WebSocketSubject, WebSocketSubjectConfig } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { AuthService } from './auth-service';
import { UrlService } from './url-service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppWsService {
private socket!: WebSocketSubject<any>;

constructor(private urlService: UrlService) {
    this.initialize();
}

private async initialize() {
    await this.fetchWebsocket();
}

private async send_message(message: any) {
    await this.fetchWebsocket();
    console.log('[BASE] Send message', message);
    this.socket.next(message);
}

public async fetchWebsocket(): Promise<WebSocketSubject<any>> {
    if (!this.socket) {
        let config: WebSocketSubjectConfig<any> = {
            url: this.urlService.get_ws_url(),
            openObserver: {
                next: (_: any) => {
                    let msg = {
                        // Include auth stuff here
                    };
                    this.socket.next(msg as any);
                },
                error: (err: any) => {
                    console.log('[BASE][WS] Error connecting:', err);
                }
            }
        };
        console.log('[BASE][WS]Making subject...')
        this.socket = new WebSocketSubject(config);
        this.socket.subscribe({
            next: (data) => {
                console.debug('[BASE][WS] Got message:', data);
                console.debug('[BASE][WS] Type:', data.constructor.name);
            },
            error: (msg) => {
                console.error('[BASE][WS] Error:', msg);
            }
        });
    }

    console.log('[BASE][WS] Returning subject')
    return this.socket;
}
}
```

Example service that uses the base websocket (simplified):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { AppWsService } from './app-ws-service';
import { ChatInfo, isChatMessage, isChatInfo, isChatInfos } from './definitions/chat-messages';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {
private ws!: WebSocketSubject<any>;

constructor(private appWsService: AppWsService) {
    this.initWebsocket();
}

private async initWebsocket() {
    this.ws = await this.appWsService.fetchWebsocket();
    this.ws.subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
            if (isChatMessage(data)) {
                // Do stuff
            } else if (isChatInfo(data)) {
                // Do stuff
            } else if (isChatInfos(data)) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```